Edits that change the question at issue
I'm new to approving edits, so I'm interested in how other edit-approvers handle situations like this.  This question (which is, IMO, not a good one as it stands) has a suggested edit which, while it certainly improves the question substantially, may also take the question in quite a different direction than intended.  Would you approve the edit because it improves the question, or reject the edit because it changes what the question is?

Link to revision history here for others joining this discussion: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/posts/8254/revisions

A major aim of the site is  to create good ongoing resources for the internet.
We get a lot of questions from lay people coming to the site. These questions can often be substantially improved. Common problems include: irrelevant details; imprecise terminology;  unclear scope; title that does not reflect question in body; sense of a problem without a well-articulated question; too many questions; etc.
I think particularly in these cases there should be a bit more scope for experienced editors to polish the question in order to make it more useful, answerable, and appropriately scoped.

I think that's a good edit. I don't see it as a major change to the question but in part that's because I don't know what the original question was really asking.
The original question appears to have had an english language barrier. This is okay, that's one reason why we accept suggested edits! If the suggested edits change the nature of the question, the question's author should ask for help in comments or re-edit (or even rollback) the edits.
Also, +1 to you for trying to use your new power well! I asked a similar question when I first got started editing.

I agree Josh--it is not at all clear what the original question was asking.  Can new users roll back edits to their own questions, or do they have to ask, uh, for lack of a better word--grownups?

Haha, users can always roll back edits on their questions. It's a form of editing, and they always have permission to edit questions they posted.
